# PowerShell formatting custom objects with the format.ps1.xml file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have created a custom object and created a generic view in the ps1.xml file and it formats great, I would like to add color to the output. How would I go about  adding color to the output in the ps1.xml file.  For example my output is a simple table in which one column has a status output for cloud servers. I would like the output to display white for active, red for stopped, yellow for rebooting etc.  I am guessing it would take a  but I have not yet found any examples or articles detailing the use of it for color in the ps1.xml file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No colors in ps1xml files in v3.
You can:

- vote up [this item on connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/288077/formatting-output-we-need-control-over-color)
- define color formatting on your own, like Jaykul did for ls, [here](http://poshcode.org/2488)

I hope v4 will finally get it. Conditionally colored output would really help to spot issues, so I guess it make perfect sense to have. Not there yet though...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yeah I hope we get a format color node for ps1.xml soon.